# When I try to insert image in control panel of my database, the image open like this

Tags: php, database

[image: Screenshot]

When I try to insert image in control panel of my database the image open like this. Please can you help me with that?

```
<div class="section-header-underline"></div>
<div class ="zoom"> <a class="zoom" href="<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" ></a>
<?php
     $i=0;
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         if($i%3 == 0){ echo"<tr>"; }
         echo"<td><img src='user_images/{$row['userPic']}' alt='{$row['userName']}' class='zoom'></td>"; 
         if($i%3 == 2){ echo"</tr>"; }
         $i++;
     }
?>
```

Comment: We need more info to help you. How you doing that? Show us your code!

Comment: <div class="section-header-underline"></div>
  <div class ="zoom">
  
  <a  class="zoom" href="<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" ></a>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($i%3 == 0){
 echo"<tr>";
}
echo"<td><img src='user_images/{$row['userPic']}' alt='{$row['userName']}' class='zoom'></td>";

if($i%3 == 2){
 echo"</tr>";
}
$i++;
 }

?>

Comment: You sould update your answer with this souce-code.

Answer (score 0):

```
this display.php
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="section-header">معرض الصور</h1>
  <div class="section-header-underline"></div>
  <div class ="zoom">

  <a  class="zoom" href="<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" ></a>
<?php
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($i%3 == 0){
    echo"<tr>";
}
echo"<td><img src='user_images/{$row['userPic']}' alt='{$row['userName']}' class='zoom'></td>";

if($i%3 == 2){
    echo"</tr>";
}
$i++;
    }

?>
....................................
this index.php

<?php

    error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE ); // avoid notice
    include_once 'includes/header.php';//header page
    require_once 'dbconfig1.php';

    if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
    {
        $username = $_POST['user_name'];// user name
        $userjob = $_POST['user_job'];// user email

        $imgFile = $_FILES['user_image']['name'];
        $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
        $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'];


        if(empty($username)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Image Name.";
        }
        else if(empty($userjob)){
            $errMSG = "Please Enter Description.";
        }
        else if(empty($imgFile)){
            $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
        }
        else
        {
            $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

            $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

            // valid image extensions
            $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

            // rename uploading image
            $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

            // allow valid image file formats
            if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
                // Check file size '5MB'
                if($imgSize < 7000000)              {
                    move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
                }
                else{
                    $errMSG = "Sorry, your image is too large.";
                }
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
            }
        }


        // if no error occured, continue ....`enter code here`
        if(!isset($errMSG))
        {
            $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userProfession,userPic) VALUES(:uname, :ujob, :upic)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$username);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ujob',$userjob);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "new image succesfully inserted ...";
                header("refresh:5;addimage.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
            }
            else
            {
                $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```